# Find $\text{Aut}\left(\Bbb{Z}_{15}\right)$ and express as product of cyclic groups of prime power order

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Find $\text{Aut}\left(\Bbb{Z}_{15}\right)$. Use the Fundamental Theorem of Abelian Groups to express this group as an external direct product of cyclic groups of prime power order.

For this would it just be as simple as $U(5) \oplus U(3)$ due to $3$ and $5$ being the only factors of $15$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{15}$? I feel as though I am definitely missing a key piece since this seems to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is indeed one valid way to do it, you are using the chinese remainder theorem.

But to conclude you need to express $U(5)$ and $U(3)$, remember that they are isomorphic to the multiplicative group of $\mathbb Z_n$, which are cyclic for primes.

So the decomposition is $\mathbb Z_4\times \mathbb Z_2$

Answer (score 0):

The automorphism group of a cyclic group is its group of units, in this case $\Bbb Z_{15}^×$.

The group of units functor respects products.  Thus, since by the Chinese remainder theorem, $\Bbb Z_{15}\cong\Bbb Z_3×\Bbb Z_5$, we get $\Bbb Z_3^××\Bbb Z_5^×\cong \Bbb Z_2×\Bbb Z_4$.

(In the last step, I used that for any prime $p$, we have $\Bbb Z_p^×\cong\Bbb Z_{p-1}$.)

Comment: ah, so the trick is to subtract  1 from each of the p values.  Is there another way to prove that aside from the Chinese remainder theorem?  I don't recall that coming up in my class at all

Comment: When $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime (and only when), we have $\Bbb Z_{mn}\cong\Bbb Z_m×\Bbb Z_n$.

Comment: That $\Bbb Z_p^×\cong\Bbb Z_{p-1}$ has to do with Euler's totient function and primitive elements mod $p$.