# Decomposition of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I know that $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb{Z}_n)\cong \mathbb{Z}_n^\times$ and in [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3639271/find-textaut-left-bbbz-15-right-and-express-as-product-of-cyclic-grou) a user correctly states that $\mathbb{Z}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times\dots\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_k}$, where the $p_i$ are $n$'s prime decomposition, and also $\mathbb{Z}_p^\times\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p-1}$.

In my case, I have a theorem stating that there are unique $1<d_1\,|\,d_2\,|\,\dots\,|\,d_r$ such that $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_{d_1}\times\dots\times \mathbb{Z}_{d_r}$. The problem is the strict inequality $d_1>1$. I want to decompose $\mathbb{Z}_{400}^\times$, but with the method above, I only get $\mathbb{Z}_{400}^\times\cong (\mathbb{Z}_1)^5\times (\mathbb{Z}_4)^2$ and clearly $1\ngtr1$.

Comment: Regarding the formula *$\mathbb{Z}_n\cong \mathbb{Z}_{p_1}\times\dots\times \mathbb{Z}_{p_k}$, where the $p_i$ are $n$'s prime decomposition*, you might wish to ponder whether $\mathbb{Z}_{12} \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z_3}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let us ask the computer, to have the answer, then we will understand it humanly:

```
sage: A = IntegerModRing(400)
sage: U = A.unit_group()
sage: U
Multiplicative Abelian group isomorphic to C2 x C4 x C20
```

So the theorem of invariant factors works for the unit group $U=A^\times$ of the abelian group $A=(\Bbb Z/400, +)$, seen as underlying abelian group of the ring $(\Bbb Z/400, +,\cdot)$. The elements of $U$ are of the shape $k$ for $k$ from $1$ to $399$ (taken modulo $400$) which is relatively prime to $400$. There are
$$
\varphi(400)
=400\left(1-\frac 12\right)\left(1-\frac 15\right)
=
400\cdot \frac 12\cdot\frac45
=160
$$
such elements.
The invariant factors are $d_1=2$, $d_2=4$, $d_3=20$, with $1$ divides $d_1=2$, which divides $d_2=4$, which divides $d_3=20$.
Explicitly:
$$
\color{blue}{
\boxed{\
(\Bbb Z/400)^\times
\cong
(\Bbb Z/2)\times
(\Bbb Z/4)\times
(\Bbb Z/20)\ .
}}
$$

---

A way to see this result is as follows.

The ring $\Bbb Z/400$ can be written isomorphically as the product
of rings $(\Bbb Z/2^4)\times(\Bbb Z/5^2)$. The units group of this ring corresponds to the multiplicative group
$$
(\Bbb Z/2^4)^\times \times(\Bbb Z/5^2)^\times\ .
$$
So let us understand the structure of the two groups explicitly.

Again, the computer tells us...

```
sage: IntegerModRing(16).unit_group()
Multiplicative Abelian group isomorphic to C2 x C4
sage: IntegerModRing(25).unit_group()
Multiplicative Abelian group isomorphic to C20
```

(The prime two is the oddest one for such computations.)
So we will show:

- The multiplicative group $(\Bbb Z/16)^\times$ is isomorphic to the additive group $(\Bbb Z/2)\times(\Bbb Z/4)$.
- The multiplicative group $(\Bbb Z/25)^\times$ is isomorphic to the additive group $\Bbb Z/20\cong\Bbb Z/4\times \Bbb Z/5$.

For the second isomorphism, it is enough to exhibit in $(\Bbb Z/25)^\times$ two elements, one of order four, one of order five. An element of order four is $7$, since $7^2=49=-1$ is not one, but $7^4$ it is. An element of order five is $6$, since $6^5=7776=1$.

For the first isomorphism we know that the isomorphic group has $\varphi(16)=8\left(1-\frac1 2\right)=8$ elements.
Let us search first for the elements of order two in $(\Bbb Z/16)^\times$.
So we solve $x^2=1$ modulo $16$. It turns out that there are four solutions, here are they: $0\pm 1$, $8\pm 1$. Three of them, $-1,7,9$ have order two. So we have two invariant factors, and these correspond to the only one possible decomposition
$(\Bbb Z/16)^\times\cong(\Bbb Z/2)\times(\Bbb Z/4)$.
(The elements of order four are $4\pm1$, $12\pm 1$, $18\pm 1$. There are no elements of order eight.)

Comment: Could you please clarify how you got to $(\Bbb Z/16)^\times\cong(\Bbb Z/2)\times(\Bbb Z/4)$ being the only possible decomposition from knowing $-1,7,9$ have order two?

Comment: $(\Bbb Z/16)^\times$ has order $8=2^3$, the only structural possibilities (theorem of invariant factors) allow at most three such factors, so we have to pick one of the following possibilities: $\Bbb Z/8$ - here only $4$ has order two, $(\Bbb Z/2)\times(\Bbb Z/4)$ - here we have the elements $(1,0)$, $(0,2)$, $(1,2)$ of order two, and  $(\Bbb Z/2)\times(\Bbb Z/2)\times(\Bbb Z/2)$ - here all elements but $(0,0,0)$ have order two. A better way to count is to look at elements of order dividing two. There are respectively $2^1$, $2^2$, $2^3$ elements for respectively $1,2,3$ cartesian components.